# Indesign CS6 margin disappeared

Tags: adobe-indesign, margin

I was using Indesign CS6 when suddenly the margin disappeared. I don't think that it was the <kbd>W</kbd> key. Which key can bring back my margin?

Comment: Hold ctrl and hit the semicolon is my guess. But this is tech support so voting to close. Pretty sure the ctrl and semicolon is your issue though if its not preview modes.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top my head I'm pretty sure it's grouped as a guide so you can try `command/alt + ;` to toggle visibility.